# how to create a form_for for multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have the costs and products table in my database and I want to get cost for all products in a cost's form then save all product_id,cost value into costs table.

My Models

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :test
end

class Product < ActiveRecord
  has_many :costs
end
```

Here I don't know better way to make form's parameter and save the records in table. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with your associations - is that :test association supposed to be :product?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Have a look at section 2.3 The has_many Association.

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord
 belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord
 has_many :costs

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Would it make more sense to have a Product form instead? So that Product index action could just be used to list all Products. Then the Product form could be used to handle multiple Costs through a fields_for tag and accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs in the Product model.

EDIT:
So going on your comment you are looking at this sort of model?

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord
  has_many :costs
  has_many :products, :through => :costs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Cost < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord
  has_many :costs
  has_many :customers, :through => :costs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did the same type of association as u mentioned. 
Here I can't get cost of the product(s) while saving product(s) attribute because cost(s) and product(s) are created with two different situations.
product(s) are created by admin user.After that all the product(s) are available to all customers.
But each customer have to set their own cost for all product(s). Cost may be vary depends on customer.
Cost(s) table have customer_id and product_id associated with it.